# Finitely generated nilpotent group is isomorphic to a quotient of the free nilpotent group.

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, finitely-generated, nilpotent-groups

Let $F^{(r)}$ be the free group generated by $r$ elements. Let $\gamma_n(F^{(r)})$ denote its lower central series. Finally, let $F_{n,r} = F^{(r)}/\gamma_{n+1}(F^{(r)})$ be the free nilpotent group of rank $r$ and step $n$.

Consider now an arbitrary nilpotent group $N$ of rank $r$. I am asked to show that $N \cong F_{n,r}/K$ for some $K \triangleleft F_{n,r}$.

I am thinking that perhaps I am meant to consider all possible word expressions of elements in $N$ in terms of some generating set $S$ of rank $n$, and then show that the things I'd want to quotient out by, when thought of as elements of $F_{n,r}$, form a normal subgroup.

Another idea I had was that I could possibly show that a general, not-necessarily nilpotent, is isomorphic to a quotient of $F^{(r)}$, but that has the similar problem of, I'm not sure how to characterise all expressions that I want to "quotient" out by.

These problems make me think that perhaps I should approach this from a different point of view. These approaches are direct in the direction of "given such an $N$, I want to find an appropriate $K$".

However, I am not really sure how else I can go about this. Perhaps there is a proof by contradiction where I may assume I have a nilpotent group that is not isomorphic to any quotient of the free nilpotent group, but then in that case I can't anticipate what exactly I would be contradicting.

I would really appreciate any advice regarding what method of proof may yield the best results for me in regards to this problem, and also how I might go about starting it if it requires some inspiration. Thank you!

Comment: "Consider now an arbitrary nilpotent group $N$ of rank $n$". You probably mean of rank $r$ ($\le r$ is enough) and $n$-step nilpotent.

Comment: @YCor yes, my apologies, thank you for pointing out the mistake. Do you have any suggestion perhaps of how I might go about this?